# How do I pass the KeyValuePair into this method?

Tags: c#, key-value, icollection

How do I pass the KeyValuePair into this method, accepting `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`?

[image]

If my header name is 'auth' and the header value is 'local'

```
_restActions.ExecutePostRequest(resource, body, {WHAT GOES HERE});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `Dictionary<string, string>` which [implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0) and, I would argue, allows the most concise instantiation syntax:

```cs
_restActions.ExecutePostRequest(
    resource, 
    body, 
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"one", "two"}, {"foo", "bar"}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass anything since there is `null` on `headers` parameter (default value).
If you do want to pass something then it would be anything like `new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("content-type", "text/plain") }`

Comment: Thank you, this also works but I went with Guru Stron suggestion

Comment: @JLee101 note that you can upvote answers which you like too)